# Centering objects next to each other in html / css with no top offsets

Tags: css, html

I have four blocks of text, and I want them to be side-by-side, centered, over a background image.

---------
x  x  x  x
--------

I would usually use a table for this but I have heard that css / html5 are good enough that tables aren't necessary any more.

And, it'd be great if, on small screens, the four blocks would convert to being 2x2, and on even smaller screens the blocks would convert to being one above the other.

-----
  x x  
  x x 
-----

or

---
 x
 x
 x
 x
---

I tried doing this with two divs (one for each row), but once I floated the objects, I could get other, undesirable configurations:

------- 
 x x x         this is bad =(
         x
-------

I tried using display:inline-block statements as suggested below, which looks like it's on the right track, but which results in the tops of the text blocks not being aligned vertically---as though the inline-block statement is inserting a linebreak.  further thoughts?

---

```
 Trying with display:inline-block :

      <div style="overflow:hidden;padding:1em;margin:1em auto;border:1px solid #bbb;font-size:150%"> <!--this holds th\
e table-thing -->

      <div style="background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.7);width:900px;margin:0px auto">
        <b>This is a heading...</b><br>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid blue;margin:0px auto;overflow:hidden;text-align:center">

        <div style="overflow:hidden; border:1px solid brown;display:inline-block"><!-- holds the first "row"-->
      <div style="height:13em;width:180px;padding:12px;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.7);color:black;margin-right:\
30px;display:inline-block">
        <b>Attribute 1</b>
        <br>
          This is a great attribute.
      </div>
      <div style="height:13em;padding:12px;width:180px;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.7);color:black;margin-right:\
30px;margin-left:0px;display:inline-block">
        <b>Cheaper</b>
        <br>
          Everyone loves ways to perform at low cost.
      </div>
      </div><!-- closes the first "row" -->
      <div style="overflow:hidden; border:1px solid green;display:inline-block"><!-- holds the second "row"-->

        <div style="padding:12px;height:13em;width:180px;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.7);color:black;margin:30px\
;margin-left:0px;display:inline-block">
          <b>Robust</b>
          <br>
            And once you do a cost reduction, continuing to perform is also important.
        </div>
        <div style="padding:12px;height:13em;width:180px;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.7);color:black;margin:30px\
;margin-left:0px;display:inline-block">
          <b>Human-safe</b>
          <br>
            Because, why not!?
        </div>
      <br>
      </div>
      </div><!-- closes the second "row" -->
      </div><!--closing out the table thing -->
```

Comment: And what u have tried?

Comment: please share your codes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your elements in a container div and use this.

```
div.container{
    text-align: center
}
.elements{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: oh, yeah, it looks like the display element is what I needed.  amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 `Flex` feature you can achieve the desire effect. And `@media-queries` you can make a responsive layout as well.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/piqehofa/1/edit)** for more clear answer.

Comment: Is this example helpful for you?